# python selenium xpath find get the second element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

The problem of constructing the path to the second element.
How to construct a path?

I'm trying to find the second element with xPath.

```
getOpis = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//article[2]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*)").text
```

This method does not work.

The below does not work either.

```
getOpis = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//article[2]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*)[2]").text
```

For the first element, using:

```
getOpis = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//article/div/div/descendant-or-self::*)").text
```

The element is downloaded correctly for first element.
What I am doing wrong that I can not get the second item.
The path must retrieve the current text from the second article element

```
File "C:\Users\media\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//article[2]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*)"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
```

Comment: We can't tell what's wrong without seeing the html source.

Comment: Please share your example url

Comment: Hello. I use a program to report currently added posts. From facebook. The mobile look of the company's facebook page. There is a code. The program distinguishes whether the post is pinned, then it has to download the contents of the second post.

Something like this: https://m.facebook.com/MPM-Moje-piękne-mieszkanie-370126770161518/posts/?ref=bookmarks&mt_nav=0

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John Gordon and King Stone. It's hard to tell without more detail, but you could try:

```
getOpis = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article/div/div/descendant-or-self::*").text
```

Using elements instead of element will return a list of the elements. You can then use:

```
getOpis[1]
```

to get the second element.

Comment: Removed the extra ")" at the end of xpath.

Comment: I transformed into:

I still download the first article. Any suggestions?

 getOpis = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article/div/div/descendant-or-self::*")
       
        getOpis=getOpis[2].text